# Show that if $\sigma=(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_m)$ and $\tau$ is any element of $S_n$, then $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}=(\tau a_1,\tau a_2,\dots,\tau a_m)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, sylow-theory

Show that if $\sigma=(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_m)$ and $\tau$ is any element of $S_n$, then $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}=(\tau a_1,\tau a_2,\dots,\tau a_m)$.

I'm not quite sure how to start this. 
The solution starts off by saying that 
$$\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}(\tau(a_i))=\tau\sigma(a_i)=\begin{cases}\tau(a_{i+1})&i<m\\\tau(a_1)&i=m\end{cases}$$ 
but I don't see why.